# Super Bowl MVP winners from the losing team

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl, super-bowl

How many times a player from the losing team was named the super bowl MVP?
Please list all these MVP winners, year it occurred, as well as the team and position they played.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only currently one instance by the player "**Chuck Howley**"

> ***Super Bowl Players that were voted MVP of the game, but were on the opposite team:***
>
> *Year*- 1971
>
> *Super Bow*l- V
>
> *Player*- **Chuck Howley**
>
> *Position*- Linebacker
>
> *Team*-   Dallas Cowboys

Source:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_Most_Valuable_Player_Award